# Unable to create file [/temp/.cache/version.txt.lck] in AWS Lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am getting the below error when using AWS lambda with Java.
I have created a Dukascopy SDK backed java service which has been deployed in AWS lambda but getting the below error:

```
020-03-17 03:33:49.421 INFO  FilePathManager - WL info is unavailable. Use default App folder for Platform data:  /home/sbx_user1051/JForex
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Unable to create file [/temp/.cache/version.txt.lck], No such file or directory
at com.dukascopy.charts.data.datacache.LocalCacheManager.<init>(LocalCacheManager.java:141)
```

Please help me understand the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such folder as `/temp`. For lambda it should be `/tmp`.

Comment: Yeah, but I am using an SDK that needs this folder. Can I create one on AWS lambda

Comment: @JeetheshKotian No you can't. The only writable folder for your function is `/tmp`. Can't create `/temp`. Maybe there is some setting in `Dukascopy` to use different temporary folder?